# Is this considered reflection and to what degree?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have an Android application (java) that was working fine when compiled with the Android 1.6 SDK using the following code from the android.provider.Contacts class:

```
Uri baseUri = Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL;
```

When the 2.0 SDK came out, the android.provider.Contacts class was depreciated and replaced with android.provider.ContactsContract.  In order to get one program to work on both 1.6 and 2.0, I compiled under 1.6 with the following change:

```
Uri baseUri = Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL;
…
try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.provider.ContactsContract$PhoneLookup");
    baseUri = (Uri) c.getField("CONTENT_FILTER_URI").get(baseUri);
} 
    catch (Exception e) {           
}
```

Since I was compiling under 1.6, I could not import android.provider.ContactsContract since it is a class known only to 2.0.  Is this considered reflection and to what degree?

**Added Comment:** After reading the "Reflection" chapter of "The Java Programming Language" (which I should have done first), I mostly now understand what you can do with reflection but a concise definition of reflection is not easy to come by. Your answers have helped to clarify what prompted my question - that once a class has been reflected on, and an instance of the class created using reflection, you can interact with the instance as if the class was new'ed.

Here is my meager attempt at a concise definition that is far from perfect and I am sure I will need to revise as I learn more:

Reflection is the indirect, dynamic inquiry, manipulation or invocation of class objects using class objects contained in java.lang.reflect or the Class or Package classes that requires initially accessing the class using a fully qualified string name.

Comment: Note that even although that URI is deprecated in 2.0, the functionality should still exist in the framework for a while (although sometimes Android has its own interpretation of the word "deprecated").

Comment: You are correct that it still exists except that the functionality under 2.0 does not work. The requested contact is not retreived.  I can't remember if it returns no contact or the "My contact card" contact every time.

Comment: Instead of the above code, and relying on a ClassNotFound exception, you could proactively check what edition of Android you code is running in through an environment property, and then switch calling a sub-function that returns a BaseURI

Comment: I tried that but I had to compile under 1.6 to get one application to run on both 1.6 and 2.0 so when running on 2.0 the android.provider.ContactsContract class is not available directly (since it was compiled in 1.6). This is why I had to use reflection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that is the very definition of [Java reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/) ([more on Android reflection for multiple-version compatibility](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html)).  I'm not sure what you mean by "to what degree"; it just is.

Comment: By to what degree I mean is that all there is to reflection? JasperE says my example is only one form implying there is more to reflection than simply "dynamically asking for the availability of a method".

Comment: Well, there are more things one can do with reflection as necessary, such as creating objects or invoking methods.  You could also use reflection just to discover what member variables and class methods a Class has.

Comment: The "Java reflection" link you provided is what I used to make the program change. I just had a hard time extracting a concise definition of reflection from it.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamically asking for the availability of a method is a form of reflection, yes.

Comment: So bottom-line, anytime you access objects using their fully-qualified names it is reflection but there are other forms of reflection?

Comment: Nop. Reflection is accessing type objects from strings or other value-types. It is, if you can hold the name of the class or method in a string variable and get it. It's reflection because the compiler doesn't know/check the value of that var.

Comment: Well, you can use reflection to invoke methods or create objects too.  It's all under the umbrella of reflection, what you have above is one aspect of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's reflection.

If `CONTENT_FILTER_URI` is a final static field, then you should use `get(null)` instead of `get(baseUri)` because you are not invoking an object.

**Edit**

I was a bit confused by your code. As I understand your snippet, first you assign `Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL` to `URL baseUri`, then you reflect the `CONTENT_FILTER_URI` field on the `PhoneLookup` class and read that fields value from the `URL` instance stored in `baseUri` - just to assign the value to `baseUri` again !? Typo or room for improvement?

Comment: The way I understand it is that the initial assignment is needed when the program runs under 1.6 and the reflected assignment is needed when running under 2.0.  Since an exception gets thrown under 2.0 the initial assignment prevails when running under 1.6.

Comment: Type - the exception gets thrown under 1.6 not 2.0 because the android.provider.ContactsContract class does not exist under 1.6.

Comment: Type - above = Typo in first comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good article on strategies, reflection and other more sophisticated things, for using new APIs while remaining compatible with older platforms:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html